# $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2+\cos x}{x^3\sin x}-\frac{3}{x^4}=\frac{1}{60}$ without using L Hospital rule or series expansion

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2+\cos x}{x^3\sin x}-\frac{3}{x^4}=\frac{1}{60}$ without using L Hospital rule or series expansion.

---

I tried $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2+\cos x}{x^3\sin x}-\frac{3}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2+\cos x}{x^4\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}}-\frac{3}{x^4}$
$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2+\cos x}{x^4}-\frac{3}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{4x^2(\frac{x}{2})^2}$
$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-1}{2x^2}$
Now it has turned into limit does not exist.I dont know where have i made mistake,because as per my knowledge my every step is correct.If i have made mistake please correct me
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: I was reading the post suggested by you,but wondering whether my question can be solved by the method suggested in this.@labbhattacharjee

Comment: @diya, [it does converge](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+0+%28%282%2Bcos+x%29%2F%28x^3+sin+x%29+-3%2Fx^4%29).

Comment: Your mistake is probably in the first step when you took the limit of $\sin{x}/x$ inside the big limit. This isn't allowed since the limit of $\frac{2+\cos x}{x^4}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes i got the answer by method suggested by @labbhattacharjee.Thank you.

Comment: @diya, you can answer your own question, always appreciated by the community!

Answer (score 2):

As per the method suggested by Lab bhattacharjee, I got the answer to my problem.Thanks to him.
Let $L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2+\cos x}{x^3\sin x}-\frac{3}{x^4}......(1)$
So $L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2+\cos 2x}{8x^3\sin 2x}-\frac{3}{16x^4}$
$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+2\cos^2x}{16x^3\sin x\cos x}-\frac{3}{16x^4}$
$16L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+2\cos^2x}{x^3\sin x\cos x}-\frac{3}{x^4}......(2)$
Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$,we get
$15 L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-2\cos x+\cos^2 x}{x^3\sin x}$
$15 L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-\cos x)^2}{x^4\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}}$
$15L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4\sin^4\frac{x}{2}}{x^4}$
$15L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4\sin^4\frac{x}{2}}{16(\frac{x}{2})^4}$
$L=\frac{1}{60}\lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}})^4$
$L=\frac{1}{60}$

Comment: You've shown if the limit exists, it equals $1/60.$ but you haven't shown the limit exists.

Comment: How can i show that limit exists.I dont know.Can you show me please?@zhw.